# eclipse ADT graphical Layout

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, eclipse-plugin, android-xml

I am trying to view my android xml file layout design-view but it is not displaying,I did some designing in XML with eclipse and ADT,

When I click on Graphical Layout it does not display anything and says 'Missing Theme',I also tried : Right click XML file>openwith>android layout editor but to no avail.
My development environment is:

Eclipse Helios Service Release 2,
Android Development Toolkit Version: 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431,
Dalvik Debug Monitor Service Version: 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431,
Traceview Version:12.0.0.v201106281929-138431.
What can be the problem` ?

My xml file as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1">
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout05"
android:layout_below="@id/RelativeLayout04" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/brightblue">
<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView06"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/SaveMyBackupTo" android:textColor="@color/black"
android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
android:lines="2" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:singleLine="false" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button09"
android:layout_marginTop="5dip"></TextView>
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/CheckBox01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:text="@string/EnableAutoSave"
android:textColor="@color/black" android:layout_below="@+id/Button09"></CheckBox>
<Button android:id="@+id/Button09" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:textSize="12dip"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="30dip"
android:text="Memory Card" android:layout_marginTop="5dip"></Button>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I uploaded a screenshot [here](http://www.imgplace.com/img833/1133/39eclipseadtlayout.th.png).
one thing i noted that my title-bar selection option menu is not change-able.

Comment: Please add your XML Code, perhaps there is a small mistake in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. solution posted [here](http://androidbridge.blogspot.com/2011/11/eclipse-layout-editor-not-showing.html).

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the `SDK level/version` from the drop-down. it solved this issue for me everytime.

Comment: hi thanks,I am using android 2.2,now from drop-down list i change android 2.3 sometimes 3.0 so to next and I again select 2.2 after selection different options,this thing make Component Pallete visible on left side,then I just drag a component for a bit from its position in Pallete this thing make graphical Layout visible.thanks @Sheikh Aman

Comment: Glad to know that it worked. If your problem is solved, please mark any answer(which solved your problem) as accepted answer